# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement Google Warning

Tags: android, google-play, apk

So I am getting below message while uploading an apk.
Now for this I have searched alot on this issue came to know that my project contains some native code from third party lib and after apk build I analyze the apk and got to know that there is lib folder and in lib folder only arc 32 bit files are being generated.

So for this I remove those third party libs which were using native development code and added those compatible third party libs which are native code free libs. Now after this I build a release apk and analyze it through apk analyzer Now through analyzer there were no lib folder generated. And then again install the apk on 32-bit and 64-bit arch separately and apk was successfully running.

Now I uploaded the app on google play store but still getting same warning.I have triple checked the apk there is no lib folder and .so file of 32-bit arch. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Warning

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 5.

From August 1, 2019 all releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More
```

**Moreover I have also added this myn build gradle file**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        ndk.abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
      bundle {
            abi {
                // Specifies that the app bundle should  support
                // configuration APKs for different arch. These
                // resources are instead packaged with each base and
                // dynamic feature APK.
                enableSplit = true
            }

            language {
                // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
                // configuration APKs for language resources. These
                // resources are instead packaged with each base and
                // dynamic feature APK.
                enableSplit = true
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Double-check that you are effectively analyzing the same APK that you upload to the Play Console. Also, the "bundle" block in the gradle config is only used when building an Android App Bundle. Are you uploading an APK or an App Bundle?

Comment: @Pierre Yes I have analyze the apk which is uploaded to the play store.
Previously I uploaded the app bundle but there was a versioning issue.
So I deleted the bundle and uploaded the apk.

Comment: @User42590 have you found any solutions by any chance, please share it with us

Comment: I have a similar issue, except I even have the problem with a new, completely empty boilerplate app.

Comment: Any news? my app is lib free and .so free and still get that error and the support team of play store always answer by refer to documentation